# Fourier Transform question using a certain property

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

If $$f(x) = \frac{1}{p}e^{\frac{-\pi x^2}{p^2}},$$ for some $p > 0$, find $F(f(x))$.

I'm thinking I need to use the scaling property.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) for how to evaluate the Fourier transform of this function.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{p}e^{-\pi p^2 u^2}$?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of normalizations for the Fourier Transform. The one that I use here is
$$
\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x)\,e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Using this normalization, $e^{-\pi x^2}$ is its own Fourier Transform. Thus, using the $f$ given above,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{F}(f)(\xi)
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(x)\,e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac1pe^{-\pi x^2/p^2}e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-\pi x^2}e^{-2\pi ipx\cdot\xi}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{$x\mapsto px$}\\
&=e^{-\pi p^2\xi^2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Time and frequency scaling on $\mathcal{F}(e^{-\pi x^2}) = e^{-\pi f^2}$gives,

$$\mathcal{F}(ae^{-\pi (ax)^2}) = e^{-\pi (\frac f a)^2}$$